# Joda-Time ISO8601 standard ISOPeriodFormat cannot parse decimal fraction

Tags: java, jodatime

As stated in the [ISO8601 wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)  :

> The smallest value used may also have a decimal fraction, as in "P0.5Y" to indicate half 
>   a year. This decimal fraction may be specified with either a comma or a full stop, as in "P0,5Y" or "P0.5Y".

But I can't parse such period with joda-time, the following code :

```java
Period.parse("P0.5Y", ISOPeriodFormat.standard());
```

fails with :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "P0.5Y" is malformed at "0.5Y"

Who's wrong : wikipedia, joda-time ISOPeriodFormat.standard() or my mistake?

*with jodatime 2.2*

Comment: have you tried ISOPeriodFormat.alternate or alternateExtended?

Comment: although from the docs it does look like it supports just a subset of the ISO8601 formats : http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISOPeriodFormat.html

Comment: none of the ISOPeriodFormat is able to parse "P0.5Y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a limitation of jodatime.  It has ISOPeriodFormat and PeriodFormatterBuilder for creating PeriodFormatters.  But ISOPeriodFormat only supports a subset of the ISO8601 formats (none including fractional years) as per link in comments.
PeriodFormatBuilder, although highly configurable, apparently will only deal with years as integers :

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html